# PHP-FPM sending empty response with Nginx on macOS

Tags: php, macos, nginx, homebrew

I installed nginx 1.10.3 and php 5.5.38 as a development server on macOS 10.12.4

When I try a test php file in my browser the body is empty but the response headers seem ok:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Wed, 29 Mar 2017 11:35:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38`

There are no errors in php-fpm.log or nginx/error.log

my nginx.conf has:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  wordpress.bob;
    root /Users/mark/Sites/wordpress;     

    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/global_restrictions.conf;
    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/wordpress.conf;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass   unix:/usr/local/var/run/php-www.sock;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      include        fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

wordpress.bob is a local hostname for testing pointing to 127.0.0.1 in etc/hosts

php-fpm.conf has:

```
listen = '/usr/local/var/run/php-www.sock'
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you right set to root path ?

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick Yes, the root path is correct. I've tested with an HTML file just using nginx. I've also got Apache running using the same PHP install so I know it works.

Comment: you may try to point `nginx` to a **different (test) directory** with a single `index.php` file with a simple `<?php`  `echo "test";` statement and see if you still have empty output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to help without the ability to read all the configuration files.

You just posted one, not the included ones nor php-fpm.conf. This is not a disapproval (a wall of configuration files is not quite appropriate in a question) but it's just to point out that the configuration file we "don't see" may differ depending on installation.

Anyway I see some differences from the configuration file I have on a server for a wordpress site.

Here are some hints considering that as you don't get any errors **php-fpm** is running and **nginx** can "communicate" to it via the socket (otherwise you would get a **bad gateway** error).

---

At the beginning...

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  wordpress.bob;
    root /Users/mark/Sites/wordpress;     

    index index.php; # <-- ADD THIS
```

Make sure in the included `wordpress.conf` you have

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

The last part...

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 512k;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 3s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 5s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 5s;
    include fastcgi.conf; # <--- fastcgi.conf, NOT fastcgi_params
    fastcgi_pass /usr/local/var/run/php-www.sock;
}
```

The difference between **fastcgi.conf** and **fastcgi_params** (on my installation) is just one line:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

If this line is missing php code is not able to read `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` and (I think) this may break wordpress code resulting in empty output.

---

Finally make sure php-fpm worker processes have privileges to access `/usr/local/var/run/php-www.sock`

Usually the socket has the same owner:group of the workers.

The workers user and group is set in php-fpm.conf:

```
; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
user = ......
group = ......
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution was include fastcgi.conf instead of fastcgi_params. user/group didn't make a difference for me.

Answer (score 1):

To install NGINX with Homebrew :

```
$ brew install nginx
```

Run NGINX :

```
$ sudo nginx
```

Test the localhost nginx :

```
http://localhost:8080
```

NGINX configuration file should be in :

```
$ /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

If you want to change the default port :

```
$ sudo nginx -s stop
$ vim /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Change the : `listen       8080;`
To : `listen       80;`

To save and Conf and start NGINX run :

```
$ sudo nginx
```

Then, according to your problem, you might simply be pointing to a an empty PHP file. Try to print a phpinfo() then look for "DOCUMENT_ROOT" to see where it goes.

Comment: Thanks but I did have something in my PHP file which isn't printing.